# Python Pandas: Get the two largest values from a set of numbers but ensure they are x amount of values apart

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use .nlargest to get the two highest numbers in a set of number, but ensure that they are x amount of rows apart?

For examples, in the following code I would want to find the largest values but ensure that they are more than 5 values apart from each other. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
   data = {'Pressure' : [100,112,114,120,123,420,1222,132,123,333,123,1230,132,1,23,13,13,13,123,13,123,3,222,2303,1233,1233,1,1,30,20,40,401,10,40,12,122,1,12,333],
       }
```

Comment: And what should be the output if they're not?

Comment: No output, the data above is a snippet from my other data thats very large, some values will be like 1,2,3,3,5,6,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1,1,1. I would need the largest to show the highest values of 6 and 4 for the data above. So i thought the best way would be to show the largest value than ignore values 3 or so after than get the next. But was not sure how to code this

Comment: Maybe you can clarify better the expected input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to output the largest value, and then the next largest value that's at least X rows apart from it (based on the index).

First value is just `data.Pressure.max()`. Its index is `data.Pressure.idxmax()`

Second value is either before or after the first value's index:

```py
max_before = df.Pressure.loc[:df.Pressure.idxmax() - X].max()
max_after = df.Pressure.loc[df.Pressure.idxmax() + X:].max()

second_value = max(max_before, max_after)
```